# Why do best practices tell you to disable caching on the log drive of SQL Server on an Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-storage

According to this article and several others I've found:
[Performance best practices for SQL Server](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance/)

It is considered a best practice to disable caching on premium storage disks for the SQL Server Log disks.  However, I can't find anywhere that explains why.

Does anyone have some insight?

Let me add that the reason I see disabling read-only cache on the log drive as an issue is because it makes you have to set up two separate Storage Pools inside the VM, which makes upgrading/downgrading VM's inside Azure more problematic and considerably less performant.

For example, say you start with a DS V13 which has a 16 drive limit, but about 6 of those drives can be maxed before you're throttled (25000 IOPs).  Since best practices says read-only cache for data and no cache for logs, you give 8 of those drives to the data and 8 to the log.

Now, the server needs to be upgraded, so you upgrade it to a DS V14.  Now you can max out 12 drives before being throttled (50000 IOPs).  However, your data drive's Storage Spaces column size is only 8, which is throttled to 40000 IOPs.  So you're not using the IO's full potential.

However, if you can start with a DS V13 and assign all 16 of those drives to a single Storage Pool then put both the log and data on it.  You can upgrade/downgrade all the way up to a DS V15 without any concern for not using up your full IOP's potential.

Another way to put it is: If you create a single Storage Pool for all 16 drives, you have considerably more flexibility in upgrading/downgrading the VM.  If you have to create two Storage Pools, you do not.

Comment: I added Azure Storage back on because I think this question has more to do with that than anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We recommend configuring “None” cache on premium storage disks hosting the log files.. Log files have primarily write-heavy operations and they do not benefit from the ReadOnly cache. Two reasons:

1. Legitimate Cache contents will get evicted by useless data from the log.
2. Log writes will also consume Cache BW/IOPS. If the cache is enabled on a disk (ReadOnly or ReadWrite), every write on that disk will also write that data into the cache. Every read will also access/put the data in the cache. Thus every IO will hit cache if the cache is ON.

Thanks,
Aung

Comment: Do you mean "we recommending disabling" instead of "we recommend setting"?  If so, seems like a good reason.

Comment: To clarify #2, when you have ReadOnly cache enabled (not ReadWrite cache), every *write* to the disk also writes to the ReadOnly cache?

Comment: Thanks Josh. Edited my reply. We recommend setting Cache setting to "None" for logs.

Answer (score 1):

Logs files are used as part of the recovery, and can help restore a database to a point in time. Having corrupt data on a log file from a power outage or hard reboot is not good with MSSQL. See the below article from MS, they relate to older versions of SQL but the purpose of the log file has not changed.

Information about using disk drive caches with SQL Server that every database administrator should know
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/234656

Description of caching disk controllers in SQL Server
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/86903

Comment: So these explain why you don't want to enable write caching, but I don't see anything about read-only caching.

Comment: I believe logs are never read, only when querying the Change Data Capture functions are they looked at so it is safer to not allow any caching on a log drive. There may be some code that checks a read, which could get out of sync after a write occurs.

Comment: Replication uses logs as well, forgot about that. Caching a log drive could cause loss of data if an outage occurs, but a write occurred, and the last read transaction is 100ms too old from the read cache.

Comment: So it sounds like you're saying when you write to Azure Storage, it is not reflected in the Read-Only cache until after a 100ms delay?

Comment: That number is one that I made up due to the way typical cache systems work. If there is a cache involved, you should assume it will return stale data, the timing is really irrelevant.